# Disable itextsharp error message

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, microstation

I develop an Bentley Microstation Addin using C# .NET 3.5. This Addin uses itextsharp to create a PDF file.

At the first itextsharp command in my case:

```
PdfReader _reader = new PdfReader("...\ab.pdf");
```

i get an message form itextsharp: 
[image]

"The itextsharp.LicenseKey could not be loaded! Reason: The Assembly is not vaild or could not be loaded by 'Assembly.LoadForm'"

After i confirmed this message the program is running fine and there is no error with the pdf. The message might be an exeption?!

If i run the PDF creation part as standalone exe there isn't any message.

I'm searching for a solution to disable or catch this error.

**edit1:** Here is the iText part of my code:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
...
PdfReader _reader = new PdfReader("D:\Test\Source.pdf");
PdfStamper _stamper = new PdfStamper(_reader, new FileStream("D:\Test\Destination.pdf", FileMode.Create));

AcroFields _fields = _stamper.AcroFields;
var _fieldKeys = _fields.Fields.Keys;

foreach (string _fieldKey in _fieldKeys)
{
    string _value = "";
    if (_DataMapping.ContainsKey(_fieldKey.Split('.').Last().Replace("[0]", "")))
        _value = _DataMapping[_fieldKey.Split('.').Last().Replace("[0]", "")];
    _fields.SetField(_fieldKey, _value);
}

_stamper.Close();
_reader.Close();
```

_DataMapping is a Dictionary of  which contains the field/value mapping.

Comment: Do you have a license key for iTextSharp? Did you [contact iText](http://itextpdf.com/contact)?

Comment: No i try to use the AGPL version.

Comment: Please show us the site where we can find your full code available under the AGPL.

Comment: Its just testing yet. So far there is nothing published - if this is necessary yet i can do so. In addition if it will work - it's only for internal purpose.

Comment: I think that the message is caused by a missing DLL. Please [contact iText](http://itextpdf.com/contact) to get this DLL.

Comment: No responce form iText. I switched to PDFSharp - a little less compfortable but working.

Comment: No response from iText? I didn't see the question turn up in the closed ticketing system, so it looks as if iText didn't receive anything. I'll create a ticket myself.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm looking forward to use iText again - it's more flexible.

Comment: Nobody at iText saw your request. How did you send it? Which name did you use? There are 7 people named "Hendrik" in our database, none of them asked a question similar to yours.

Comment: Are you trying to use XFA Worker?

Comment: Michaël: I don't think so - i added the iText code to my question. Bruno: I used my gmail adress cause of my companys file filters. I won't publish it here. - Should i resend the request using the contact formular?

Answer (score 5):

You need the licensekey dll, which is available here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/license-key-download

You then need to insert the following call *before* any other iText method calls:

```
LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(“path/to/itextkey.xml”)
```

Note that you mention "I try to use the AGPL version." However, the only time this error message would show up is when you use XFA Worker. XFA Worker doesn't exist in an AGPL version. If you want to use XFA Worker, a commercial license is required.

Comment: Just referencing the licensekey dll without adding any LicenseFile removes the error message. Can i use this solution or will i need a license to use this dll? - As i mentioned above the error only appears when i use the code inside a Bentley Microstation Addin.